# initializing private class variable of std::string&

Tags: c++, c++11

How can I initialize my private variable in my c++ class?

a.h:

```
class A {
    private:
        std::string& name;
    public:
        A(void);
        ~A(void);

        bool load(std::string& name);
};
```

a.cpp:

```
#include <string>
#include "a.h"

A::A(void) {  
    this->name = "";  
}
A::~A(void) {}


bool A::load(std::string& name) {
    this->name = name;
}
```

The error:

```
a.cpp: In constructor ‘A::A()’:
a.cpp:3:1: error: uninitialized reference member in ‘std::__cxx11::string& {aka class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&}’ [-fpermissive]
 A::A(void) {
 ^
In file included from a.cpp:2:0:
a.h:3:22: note: ‘std::__cxx11::string& A::name’ should be initialized
         std::string& name;
```

I have initialized it in my constructor (in a.cpp), but it is still erroring.

Comment: Why do you need `name` to be a `string&`? Why no just a `string`? Making a class data member a reference is complicated stuff, because you cannot have it uninitialized to some *actual* string from the very beginning.

Answer (score 3):

Let's fix the default constructor first: you cannot initialize references with an assignment. They need to be initialized with the initializer list:

```
static string empty_name("");

A::A(void) : name (empty_name) {  
}
```

Note the use of `empty_name` variable, scoped to translation unit. This lets you initialize a reference member to some object.

As far as the `load` member function goes, there is no way to re-assign a reference after it has been created. If you need this functionality, your best bet is to replace a reference with either a pointer if you need to access an external `std::string` object, or a copy (i.e. `std::string name`) if you do not need to reference a string that is external to your object.